# Can I directly access the grpc port to execute SQL or write data?

Tags: cnosdb

The sql api provided by the official document is the http protocol. But when I configured cnosdb, I found that he also provided the grpc port. What does the grpc port of cnosdb do? Can I directly access the grpc port to execute SQL or write data?